# Loss and accuracy reaches plateau at low values

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

Anyone knows what is the issue with my CNN-LSTM model? I have tried decreasing the learning rate from 0.001 to 0.0001 to 0.00001, and tried increasing the batch_size, but it still doesn't work. I have shuffled my data and loaded my data for each batch using custom keras data generator. I am training on npy files consisting of mp.holistic landmarks (flattened into 1662 points), with all data have 233 number of frames or sequence length.
My model:

```
input_shape = (233, 1662)
learning_rate = 0.00001
'''CNN + LSTM layers'''
        optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.learning_rate)
        model = Sequential()
        #1D CNN
        model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", input_shape=self.input_shape))
        model.add(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
        model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
        #LSTM
        model.add(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))
        model.add(LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))
        model.add(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=False, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(self.num_classes, activation='softmax'))
        model.build(input_shape=self.input_shape)
        model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=["sparse_categorical_accuracy"])
        model.summary(show_trainable=True)
```

Epoch data outputs:

```
Epoch 3/50
156/156 [==============================] - 140s 894ms/step - loss: 7.5935 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0015
Epoch 4/50
156/156 [==============================] - 140s 895ms/step - loss: 7.5903 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0015
Epoch 5/50
156/156 [==============================] - 140s 895ms/step - loss: 7.5874 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0015
Epoch 6/50
156/156 [==============================] - 141s 897ms/step - loss: 7.5846 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0015
Epoch 7/50
156/156 [==============================] - 142s 907ms/step - loss: 7.5820 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0015
```

Initially I thought my model was underfitted, but after trying to solve using the solutions for underfitting but none of them solves the problem of mine.

Comment: Your learning rate is probably too small, the default for Adam is 0.01

Comment: I have tried increasing the learning rates as well. At 0.01, the accuracy and loss values are same as above. But when increasing the learning rate to 0.1, the loss value becomes NaN.

Comment: Then you are probably having vanishing/exploding gradients.